# Category Page Template not Showing Posts

Tags: posts, categories

I am trying to get this template to work.

Comment: You shouldn't create your own custom WP_Query in category template. You should use global one. And if you need to modify it, you should use `pre_get_posts` action to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never create your own custom `WP_Query` queries on category templates (or any other archive template) and use them as main loop.

Why? Because it will break pagination. WordPress will still create all pagination links for such archives based on default query.

So if you want to modify the query in such way, that is should get all posts ordered by date, then you should use `pre_get_posts` action (add this to `functions.php` file):

```
function show_all_posts_on_category_archives( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );  // you shouldn't need this one - date is default value
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posts_on_category_archives' );
```

And after using that code you can use typical loop in your template file:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ...
endwhile;
```

Comment: Yes, after adding it to functions.php you should see all posts on category archive.

Comment: It's because the action above is checking for the category archive to modify only queries for this template. If you want to modify other query, you'll have to target other page with the condition inside your action.